# add shoppy.gg to woocommerce instead of add to card

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

i need for every product this:
BUY NOW
so instead of the add to card button this button is shown ( for every product an custom link

This is the code:
https://pastebin.com/FJrKwfwb